# TCL is adding different tab widths in the program

Tags: tabs

I am trying to rearrange the columns of below file

input.txt,

Contents of this file:

```
Name      Location      Purpose
---------------------------------------------
Andy      US            Business1
bob       UK            Business2
```

output_obtained

```
Name      Purpose       Location
---------------------------------------------
Andy      Business1     US
bob                     Business2     UK
```

Expected_output

```
Name      Purpose       Location
---------------------------------------------
Andy      Business1     US
bob       Business2     UK
```

TCL file:

```
set fh [open input.txt r]
set fp [open output.txt w]
while {[gets $fh line]>=0} {
if {[regexp "^-" $line]} {
puts $fp $lin
} else {
puts $fp "[lindex $line 0]\t[lindex $line 2]\t[lindex $line 1]"
}
}
close $fh
close $fp
```

I cannot understand why the tab is interpreted differently on the last row

Comment: What does this have to do with Emacs?

Comment: I posted it on the wrong forum. Not sure how do I delete this questions from here